# CSS: Change styles based on adjacent sibling

Tags: css, css-selectors, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a pure CSS solution for displaying placeholder text in an input which also becomes the label above once focused, as seen in many Google Material frameworks.

I have the default state and the focus state working, but after the user enters a value I need to change the <label> style and can't figure out (if it's even possible) to read the adjacent input and if it's input:valid change the style of the <label>

I can't modify the hierarchy of the HTML due to honoring Bootstrap 4

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="placeholder" for="exampleInputEmail1">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
</div>
```

As you can see the <input> and <label> are on the same level, is there any way to change <label> based on the input:valid pseudoclass?

You can see a semi-working example here: https://codepen.io/FritzAPI/pen/ERMvvR

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');

/* Fritz Material Placeholder Start */
.form-group:focus-within label:not(.form-check-label):not(.custom-control-label) {
    color: #2196F3;
}
label:not(.form-check-label):not(.custom-control-label) {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
}
.form-group:focus-within label.placeholder:not(.form-check-label):not(.custom-control-label) {
    color: #2196F3;
    top: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
label.placeholder:not(.form-check-label):not(.custom-control-label) {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.38);
    position: relative;
    top: 28px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
    z-index: -1;
}
/* Fritz Material End */

body {
  text-align: left;
  text-align: start;
  background-color: white;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font-family: Roboto, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.428572;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Forms, Input Group Start */
.form-control:focus, .form-control-file:focus, .custom-select:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #2196f3;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 -1px #2196f3;
  outline: 0;
}
.form-control, .form-control-file, .custom-select {
    height: 2.0rem;
    line-height: 1.428572;
    padding: 0.410714rem 0 0.348214rem;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42);
    border-radius: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
/* Forms, Input Group End */
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="placeholder" for="exampleInputEmail1">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
</div>
```

After the <input> has a value I need the label to stay above the input when losing focus.

Comment: Please edit your question to describe what you want your code to do (how do you want to style the `<label>` element based on the validity of the `<input>`). and include the code in your question. Linking to a (nearly) working demo is a very useful and welcome bonus, but it's not a replacement for including the relevant [mcve] code in your question.

Comment: @DavidThomas I added the code and the desired outcome to the question.

Comment: Many thanks! Given I'm currently on mobile - and that's a *lot* of 'minimal' code - the solutions I'd recommend are using either `display: flex` on the parent `.form-group` element, placing the `<label>` after the `<input>`, and using the `order` property (or reversing the flow) to reorder the contents so that the `<label>` appears first. That, or do the same thing, but using CSS Grid and template-areas to reorder the content.

Comment: @DavidThomas that's the core issue here, I can't change the order of the HTML as Bootstrap expects the label to be before the input.

Comment: Can you add class-names to the `.form-group` element to match the validity, then add - for example - `.form-group.hasValidInputElement > label` - to the selectors that translate the `<label>` element's position? Because without reordering the HTML this won't be possible with pure CSS. At least not until/unless CSS `:has()` selector sees the light of day.

Comment: @DavidThomas That's what I was afraid of, this became really easy once switching the order all I had to do was put my styles in `input:not(:valid) + label.placeholder` to get all 3 states working (default/focus/has value)

Comment: @DavidThomas in case you wanted to see it working using your flex order hack: https://codepen.io/FritzAPI/pen/KeYgGm